# Intellisense with AvalonEdit

Tags: intellisense, avalonedit

I have not found any good example or article about this, there is some code in this example, but its very basic and not usable for a real situation...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical example of using Intellisense with AvalonEdit is probably [SharpDevelop](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop), you could start looking at how the [CompletionWindow](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/697ff0d38c95c9e5a536fbc05ae2307ec9ef2a63/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/CodeCompletion/CompletionWindowBase.cs) is used in SharpDevelop, and start exploring the code that invokes it.